# Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException in Azure DevOps Gradle Task

Tags: gradle, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, liferay

I am building a Java Liferay application in Azure pipeline using Gradle Task.

[image]

The application has multiple modules. Occasionally I am getting the below error. Please anyone let me know how to solve this issue.

```
Task :modules:MyModule2:buildCSS FAILED
Using native Sass compiler 
There are no files to compile 
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: C:\Windows\SERVIC~1\NETWOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\portalCssImportPath6020035476982997428\com.liferay.frontend.css.common-5.0.8.jar\bourbon\functions     
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:266)  
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:103)    at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1126)  
at com.liferay.css.builder.internal.util.FileUtil$1.postVisitDirectory(FileUtil.java:56)    
at com.liferay.css.builder.internal.util.FileUtil$1.postVisitDirectory(FileUtil.java:49)    
at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2688)    
at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2742)    
at com.liferay.css.builder.internal.util.FileUtil.deltree(FileUtil.java:47)     at com.liferay.css.builder.CSSBuilder.close(CSSBuilder.java:137)    
at com.liferay.css.builder.CSSBuilder.main(CSSBuilder.java:81)
```

Comment: a) what version(s)? b) is it reproducible locally as well? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: (a) Are you asking about gradle version? If so it is 6.8. (b)Yes. It is reproducible rarely.

Comment: All versions - Liferay's (down to the build/GA). Also, as you say "occasionally": Can you describe this in a more specific way?

Comment: Liferay version is 7.3. As I am doing the build in Azure Pipeline, I am getting success if run the pipeline with clean source and clean build. But I am facing the issue if I am doing without clean source and without clean build. And one time I am getting this issue for one module and some time I am getting the similar issue for different module.